# Python to check if two or more lists are subsets of List

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have three lists which are dynamically generated. The other two lists are subset of the main list.

```
list_M = ["A", "B", "C" ,"D", "E"]    #main list
list_X = ["A", "C" , "E"]          #subset of main list
list_Y = ["A" ,"E"]           #subset of both list_X and main_list
```

What I need to do is check if items in sublists exist in main list or not and if they exist I want to replace them with "YES" and if not then replace with "NO". Like this:

```
#output
A  Yes  Yes
B  No   No
C  Yes  No
D  No   No
E  Yes  Yes
```

I can do this with a bunch of for and if statements. But is there a more pythonic way that would use `Any` and `Replace`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

list-comprehensions are your friends here:

```
list_M_x = ['YES' if i in list_X else 'NO' for i in list_M]
list_M_y = ['YES' if i in list_Y else 'NO' for i in list_M]
print(list_M_x)  # ['YES', 'NO', 'YES', 'NO', 'YES']
print(list_M_y)  # ['YES', 'NO', 'NO', 'NO', 'YES']
```

As @tobias_k says in the comments, if lists `list_X` and `list_Y` are long, you can see significant benefit by converting them to sets since sets have O(1) membership test.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so:

```
for l in list_M:
    print(f"{l} {'Yes' if l in list_X else 'No'} {'Yes' if l in list_Y else 'No'}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `issubset`

(documentation for method)
https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/issubset.html

This works by casting the list to a set, because sets only have unique elemets.

Here is an example of how you can do it with just casting the list's to sets:

```
list_M = ["A", "B", "C" ,"D", "E"]    #main list
list_X = ["A", "C" , "E"]          #subset of main list
list_Y = ["A" ,"E"]   


>>> set(list_M) < set(list_X)
True
```